# Interpretation of Moving Average coefficient in ARIMA and its equivalance with exponential smoothing parameter

Tags: arima, statsmodels, moving-average, exponential-smoothing

On Running an ARIMA (0,0,1) model from statsmodels.api on a differenced time series say X(t). I get the following output

const = 5.34e-06
ma.L1 = 0.8934

How should I interpret the above MA model with parameter 0.8934 in terms of an equivalent exponential smoothing formulation with smoothing parameter.

X^(t) = X(t - 1) - 0.8934*( X(t - 1) - X^(t - 1))
= 0.8934*X^(t - 1) + (1 - 0.8934)*X(t - 1)

The above assumes an underlying MA(1) formulation as
X^(t) = X(t - 1) - theta*e(t - 1)

but if I assume X^(t) = X(t - 1) + theta*(X(t - 1 ) - X^(t - 1))
= -0.8934*X^(t - 1) + 1.8934*X(t - 1)

The second one is a more followed convention but looks like the first interpretation
yields a more intuitive result.

Comment: 1. An MA(1) model does not have an equivalent exponential smoothing formulation.  2.  Please use Mathjax to format your math!  3. Your notation is not clear; you don't define your terms, e.g., what is X^(t-1)?  That would usually be read as X to the power t-1.